# How to list event details in a calendar card display and filter events

Tags: interaction-design, information-architecture, filter, calendar

I am re-designing a recruiting events calendar that will display each event in a card format. Here's a bit of background - recruiting happens in a two month time span, so a full month calendar display is probably more robust than necessary in this case. Events will happen in 8 states and also in the UK a handful of times.

The following information will be included for each event: Date, Time, City, State, College where event is being held, Event Title.

I have a couple of questions. What makes the most sense in terms of the hierarchy of details? How do you think users will want the events filtered?

Comment: What values would the event title field normally have? I ask because it might not be necessary given that, from what I understand, all the events have the same objective, so titles can be formed using the other information: "Recruiting at DePaul University, Chicago, IL"

Comment: Should users be able to see past events?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of guessing, its always better to go out and speak to potential users.
However considering the potential users are people looking out for a job, through these recruiting events, here are some suggestions:

1) **Where** takes precedence than **When**. If an event is 400 miles away from me, I would probably think twice, but if there is an event near me, then that is very favorable. Time in that case is hardly an issue.

2) Instead of just relying on filters, why not try to make the interface more **intelligent**. Possibly, you could geo-locate and sort the cards in terms of proximity to users location, starting with one nearest to him? How about showing a map with these recruitment event places marked together? One could *possibly* use that to travel to a place/state/location, where there are lots of events happening (cluster of markers). I mean the idea is to not constrain yourself to just using filters.

3) Are there no more details like recruitment drive for certain skills etc? If there are such filters (skill), could be very relevant.

Comment: Happy it helps!

Answer (score 1):

For the hierarchy of the details in an event, I'd do the following, assuming this is a single view in the general UI.

1. College, city, state, country
2. Title
3. Date/Time

---

Users should be able to filter by location (college, city, state, country), group by date/time and search with keywords.

Comment: Ah! got it. I was looking at the problem from the recruiter's POV. Let me edit my answer, then.